# How to store specific object in HttpSession

Tags: java, session, servlets

I'm trying so send a User object using HttpSession in login and retrieve data from jsps and some servlets. 

Here is how I save object to session in login servlet.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();  
User user = new User(1, 001);
user.setType(1);
session.setAttribute("user", user);
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

In index.jsp I do some dropdown name list loading.And when dropdown is clcked I go to this servlet. **(That dropdown selection process is working perfect. This problem is occured after I use objects with session. Other time I only set values to session not entire object and never faced this problem.)**
And here is how I retrieve them in servlet

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
            if (user != null) {
                int userid = user.getId();
                int usertype = user.getType();
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOOOOOO");
            }

}
```

likewise I call this User object in several servlets. But sometimes when I refresh the page this user object is get empty. I don't know how to fix this. Is something wrong with my data retrieving method. 

 Thank you.

Comment: @Mihir I don't think your suggestion would even compile :-(

Comment: `But sometimes when I refresh the page`... What is "the page?"  Is this page the user sees after login?

Comment: You are redirecting to `index.jsp` not to any servlet.

Comment: @Tim yes.. sorry I forget to mention that

Comment: @Task take a look at the question now. You'll have an idea.

Comment: Have you turned off the cookies ?